# in php, what is the difference bethween require and require_once

Tags: php

I learn php and I saw a code where require is use and other one where require_once instead. So, I whanted to know why use require instead of require_once.

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/require_once

Comment: A suggestion for the future, do some research before posting a question. This is one of those questions that has been asked and answers _many_ times here on SO and on _multiple_ other sites for years. If you simply google on your title, you would have found the answer faster than it took you to write this duplicate question.

Comment: `_once` , is the difference, one note is they are not functions so you dont need the `(..)` I see that in code all the time.  I'm to lazy to type those, but thats me.